# Load Runner Enterprise POST response

Tags: performance, post, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, loadrunner

I am using Azure pipelines to run a test on Load Runner Enterprise. The test is successful but I want to capture the POST response in my Powershell Script (Also running as a task in Azure pipelines). The picture attached shows my Load Runner Enterprise test results through Dev Tools on the browser. The circled portions are how I found the POST response.

How would I go about capturing this post response in my Powershell Script?

[Load Runner Enterprise Results using Dev Tools in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRjhB.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am a nearly three decade user of LoadRunner and I cannot quite fathom what you are trying to do here.  Do you want to call a powershell script from within a LoadRunner script to do something with the response?   You can capture any response as a correlated item.   You can send any string, including a correlated response to a output window.  You can change the log levels for a single statement to send the response to a log.  You can sent a correlated item to a queue to be used by another user.   Please clarify they "why" and your goals here.

Comment: @JamesPulley 
I have a powershell script as a task in my Azure Dev Ops pipeline. I also have a Load Runner Enterprise task in the pipeline that executes tests. My powershell script can easily pull data like the Run ID or test ID from tests that have been completed in Load Runner Enterprise. However, I would like to capture the POST response from a completed Load Runner Test. The post response is shown in the picture attached to the question. How would I go about doing this? Possibly an API call?

Comment: What is the nature of POST in this question?   Is this an HTTP POSt within a business process that you want to correlate for the resuls of to use later in a test.  Or, is this POST referencing an after action condition in your pipeline that you are trying to capture.  The picture is not clear is all it shows is devtools.   This could be an app or this could be an after test action.  Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

This is a powershell question, not a LoadRunner question.  You need an HTML parser incorporated into your pipeline to pull data off of a page object.